# int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'method'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

In django 1.8 /python 3.4

How can I do method to int？

example:

models.py

```
class Bid(models.Model):
    bid_Price = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.bid_Price

    def topPrice(self):
        return 100
```

view.py

```
def BidView(request, bid_id):
    bid_data = Bid.objects.get(id=bid_id)
    if int(bid_data.topPrice_text) < 100):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way it's written your method is already returning an int, so what you would have to do is actually call the method to use its return value:

`if bid_data.topPrice() < 100:`

I do have to say that I don't quite know what you're trying to do here, but `topPrice` probably shouldn't be a method anyways.

Comment: Yeah, there are a number of problems and inconsistencies here, but referring to the method (`bid_data.topPrice`) rather than calling it (`bid_data.topPrice()`) is the one that would lead to the given exception.